# How to enable scrolls when browser resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have simple html table on the page. I want to add horizontal-vertical scroll bars to the table when the browser is resized to continue showing the table content.

How can I do this?

Comment: resized to grow? or to shrink? or both?

Comment: @Reigel, shrink only. But scrolls will disappear when i grow the page again.

Answer (score 2):

In the table element... eg: `Iframe`, `frameset`, `div` etc... add:

```
scrolling="auto"
```

[Element scrolling](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_iframe_scrolling.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS using [`style="overflow: auto;"`](http://htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/overflow/) or `style="overflow: scroll;"`.